# Capturing a table value in a temp variable that won't change

Tags: vba, ms-access

So, let's say I have something like this:

```vb
Do While Rec.EOF = False
    'Capture the temp numbers right when you get to the new record, because the table values can change
    ODN = Rec("OpenDayNumber")
    CDN = Rec("CloseDayNumber")

    If Rec("OpenDayNumber") >= X1 and =< Y1, then
        'If the next record starts during the current one but ends after the current one...
        If Rec("CloseDayNumber") > Y1, then
            'Just set the OpenDayNumber of the following record to the CloseDayNumber of the current one
            ' so it doesn't double-count any days
            Rec.Edit
            Rec("OpenDayNumber") = Y1
            Rec.Update
        else
            'Ignore Rec (X + 1), it occurred entirely during Rec X.  Set its TotalPendDays to 0.
            Rec.Edit
            Rec("OpenDayNumber") = Rec("CloseDayNumber")
            Rec.Update
        end if
    else
        'its a legit new pend, and should be counted in its entirety
    end if  


    X1 = ODN
    Y1 = CDN    
    rec.MoveNext

Loop
```

How could I make X1 and Y1 capture the values of ODN and CDN respectively?  Once the data changes in the table, the variable will change values.  Well, `Rec("CloseDayNumber")` doesn't ever change, but `Rec("OpenDayNumber")` can change.  I want X1 to equal the value of ODN prior to any changes being made.

Comment: It would be nice to know the initial values of X1 and Y1 before entering this code fragment.  Also, please include some sample data and expected results. Since X1 & Y1 are used in the above to govern the updates, then some other var, say InitX1, might be needed, which could be set the first time into the above code after DoWhile // If firsttime then InitX1 = ...  and set not firsttime.

Comment: *"Once the data changes in the table, the variable will change values."*  What variable will supposedly change?  The values assigned to variables ODN and CDN come from the fields' Value properties, like `ODN = Rec("OpenDayNumber").Value` and so they will not change due to the recordset edit.  You are NOT assigning ODN and CDN to be the Field objects themselves.  (That would require a `Set` keyword.)  As far as I can tell, X1 will already be set equal to the value of ODN which was retrieved **before** changes to the recordset, so X1 will end up with the original value of ODN. What am I missing?

Comment: BTW, what are the extra commas in both `if` statements?

Comment: @CPerkins is right. You are not writing English but code, and it couldn't compile as is.